# How to hide scrollbars using jquery and scrolling divs without disabling rest of page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

See my problem here:
http://jsfiddle.net/nM6DF/

I want to have divs scroll on and off the screen using jquery, but I do not want any horizontal scrollbars. The only way I know how to do that is to make a container and do `overflow:hidden`. Here is my container CSS

```
#container {
  top:0px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;  
}
```

I had to make the width and height 100% so that no matter what I scrolled across it would not be cut off.

When I make this container then everything behind it becomes unclickable and pretty much disabled. I want the page behind the scrolling divs to still behave normally where I can click and interact with it. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Why not hide horizontal scrollbars instead? You can't put a div on top of other content and still expect the other content to be clickable.

Comment: How do you hide horizontal scrollbars? Is it cross browser compatible?

Comment: @cconoly Assuming you get this to work the way you want it. How do you distinguish whether you clicked on the container or the elements behind it?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dieegov/nM6DF/4/ ??

Comment: @AlexShilman I don't want to know if I clicked on the container. The only reason I have the container is to get rid of the scroll bars. I would like the scrolling divs to be clickable, but also have everything around it (not directly behind it) clickable as well.

Comment: @DiegoVieira I want the scrolling divs to come across the page. So making the container `position:relative` just puts it below everything else at the end of the page, where I want it at the top.

Comment: @cconoly Place the #container on top of your code html, like http://jsfiddle.net/dieegov/nM6DF/5/ and http://jsfiddle.net/dieegov/nM6DF/5/embedded/result/ (see, overflow works fine)

Comment: @DiegoVieira That worked in jsfiddle but not in my actual application. I cannot really have it be the first thing in the HTML because it messes up some other things, and if I put it at the end then it is below everything. I pretty much have to keep it `position:absolute`

Comment: @cconoly Copy my JS and CSS, both are edited.